# Run Telerik Test Studio test on the simulator

Tags: testing, console, ios-simulator, telerik-test-studio

I'm trying to add a step on my Jenkins server for testing my iOS app automatically. I know [how](http://www.telerik.com/automated-testing-tools/blog/12-10-19/deploy-test-studio-for-ios-to-the-simulator.aspx) to deploy the TestStudio app on the simulator but I have to:

1. run the Test Studio app on the simulator from the Terminal console
2. execute the test (still from terminal)

I think that using terminal commands is the best solution to integrate this operation in a Jenkins job,but if anybody comes up with a better idea I would be more than happy to hear that. Any idea how to perform these tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently it is not possible to execute Test Studio for iOS tests from the command line.

Our next major version, due out in early 2013, includes an API automation framework. With that you can write coded unit tests that can be triggered from the command line and integrated with Jenkins.