# Execute iOS monotouch GUI tests automatically from command line

Tags: ios, unit-testing, testing, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator

I am trying to find out how to test GUI of my monotouch app automatically from command line? I mean execute GUI tests in iOS simulator from CL.
Only way of GUI testing I found was Teleric tool, but it is [not automated yet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13496473/run-telerik-test-studio-test-on-the-simulator)

Some tips?
Thanks

Comment: Does it have to be from the command line? Will any scripts do, as long as they're write once, run multiple times (and fully automated, of course)?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for something to help you with TDD, you might be interested in calabash: https://github.com/calabash/calabash-ios

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `UIAutomation` framework to achieve automated GUI tests. It's not strictly from the command line but you run Javascript scripts through the Instruments tool. It works perfectly with Monotouch (the time's I've used it, anyway).

[The apple documentation on UIAutomation is pretty in depth; and hopefully should cover everything else you need.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html)

To give an example of a script ([Credit to jacksonh from Gist for this script; shamelessly taken from there).](https://gist.github.com/2719096)

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
var window = UIATarget.localTarget().frontMostApp().mainWindow ();
var table = window.tableViews () [0];
var results_cell = table.cells () [0]
var run_cell = table.cells () [1];
var passed = false;
var results = '';

run_cell.tap ();

while (true) {

   target.delay (5);

    try {
        results = results_cell.name ();
    } catch (e) {
        UILogger.logDebug ('exception');
        continue;
    }

    if (results.indexOf ('failure') != -1) {
        passed = false;
        break;
    }
    if (results.indexOf ('Success!') != -1) {
        passed = true;
        break;
    }
}

UIALogger.logDebug ('Results of test run:  ' + results);
UIALogger.logDebug ('Passed:  ' + passed);
```